# Prepared statement fetches all the results in db, but not one I ask for

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Trying to make my blog secure and learning prepared statements.

Although I set the variable, I still get all the entries from database. $escapedGet is real variable when I print it out. It's obviously a rookie mistake, but I cant seem to find an answer.

I need to get the data where postlink is $escapedGet not all the data.

```
    $escapedGet = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['article']);

        // Create statement object
            $stmt = $con->stmt_init();

        // Create a prepared statement
        if($stmt->prepare("SELECT `title`, `description`, `keywords` FROM `post` WHERE `postlink` = ?")) {

         // Bind your variable to replace the ?
         $stmt->bind_param('i', $postlink);

         // Set your variable   
          $postlink = $escapedGet;

          // Execute query
           $stmt->execute();

           $stmt->bind_result($articleTitle, $articleDescription, $articleKeywords);

            while($stmt->fetch()) {
              echo $articleTitle, $articleDescription, $articleKeywords; 
             }

          // Close statement object
          $stmt->close();
        }
```

just tryed this: `echo $escapedGet;
            echo $_Get['artcile']`

and got - some_other 
thats the same entry that I have saved in database as postlink

tried to shande postlink to id, and then it worked. but why not with postlink tab?

Comment: canu show me the table and  $escapedGet value

Comment: I tried to use $_GET['article'] instead of $escapedGet, same results, then I tried to use exact value of database, and still got all the results.

Comment: try to put a static value in place of $escapedGet then we can find the problem where it is

Comment: this is just yet another typo question. You are running not the code you posted but some other one. Please pay more attention to such things.

Comment: nope Im running the exact code.

Comment: I just echoed echo $escapedGet; echo $_Get['artcile']; and the values are the same and exactly as I saved them in database.

Comment: This is just ridiculous, Im not faking the code. wtf?

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work with text but only numbers.. why is that?

Comment: because you're binding it as 'i' means integer

Comment: ok. found out that it needs to be as 's'. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are binding your data using `'i'` modifier, it gets bound as integer. 
Means string will be cast to 0 in the final statement.

But as mysql does type casting, your strings become zeroes in this query:

```
SELECT title FROM post WHERE postlink = 0;
```

try it and see - for the textual postlinks you will have all your records returned (as well as a bunch of warnings).

So, bind strings using `s` modifier, not `i`